# Hard Disk which was running on Ubuntu is not recognized in windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I tried to use my internal hard drive as external from a laptop which was running on Ubuntu Operating system. But the problem is i can't access the drive in windows. I can see the drive in the "Disk Management" and also in the 'safely remove' icon in the system tray.Any help would be greatly appreciated. Seems like installing Ubuntu has overwritten some settings.

Answer (score 1):

Linux has built-in support for Windows NTFS partitions, but Windows can’t read Linux EXT partitions without third-party software.

You could check out [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) or DiskInternals [LinuxReader](https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/) .